# Frame rate settings for usb_cam?

Tags: usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to interface my webcam using the usb_cam package and am having success.
But it's only pumping out images at 6 fps.
Is there a config I can change to increase my frame rate?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11620/frame-rate-settings-for-usb_cam?/) by [AMoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/644/amoon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-20**:
what image size have you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The frame rate is limited by shutter speed, so it may be affected by auto-shutter, auto-exposure or other settings, depending on ambient light level.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i just had a brief glance on the source file and wiki but couldn't see any fps parameters.  there doesn't seem to be a limitation by looprate.sleep.

I guess the limitation is related to hw or libusb.
Try changing image size or use another driver like [uvc_cam2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/uvc_cam2) or [similiar](http://www.iheartrobotics.com/2010/05/testing-ros-usb-camera-drivers.html)

cheers Mimax

---

Originally posted by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) with karma: 174 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1